# Setting up thresholds for IOPS and throughput

Tags: postgresql, azure, amazon-rds, dynatrace

I am looking to setup alerting when IOPS/Throughput limit exceeds beyond the provided limit. This is for hyperscalar postgresql. We have different cloud providers like AWS, Azure, GCP. Each of them provide different DB Plans and each plan have their own IOPS/Throughput offering. Is there any way I can get the max offered IOPS/Throughput from default posgtresql internal tables?
I am using Dynatrace to monitor the DB. Can we get the info from dynatrace?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can measure it on the operating system with tools like `iostat`. But this is certainly not related to software development.